# Why does my picture doesn't show it full self?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Here is my css:

```
.navbarLogo {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 7%;
                height: 7%;
                background: url(/Images/Logo.png) no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
                transform: translateY(20%);
                transform: translateX(20%);
                z-index: 10;
            }
```

Html:

```
<div>
            <div class="navbar" href="#home">
                <navbarText class="navbarBtnAbs">home</navbarText>
            </div>
            <div class="navbarFixed" href="#home">
                <navbarText class="navbarBtnFixed">home</navbarText>
            </div>
            <div class="navbarPic">
                <div class="navbarLogo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And that's what show up:

[image: The actual result]

And what I want it to be:

[image: What I want to see]

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the css the background is set to the image.

```
.navbarLogo {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: url(your path) no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            transform: translateY(20%);
            transform: translateX(20%);
            z-index: 10;
        }
```

The width and height calculates how big the space is you make available for your image. If your image is bigger than height 200px it will be cut off. If you only want to make it fit within the width height you have given you can use

```
background-size:contain;
```

or you can give it a value `background-size:200px 200px;` or a percentage `background-size:10%;`